# UWP user permissions inside an app

Tags: uwp, azure-sql-database

We are working on a requirements document for an application that will be used to store data for several different companies.

Companies will subscribe to our service, upload data, then be notified when different actions occur.

I need to forms of security.

First I need an authentication to the app and azure sql data.  This authentication needs to restrict the user to only see there company data.  Possible company and site/location restrictions depending if the company has multiple sites or not.

In addition we need to have user roles within the app.  The companies need the ability to restrict users to certain functions within the app based on what the want there employees to perform.

We are wondering if anyone knows of a tutorial or has some knowledge on a good way to perform these task?

Comment: Please give us some context about what you've tried, resources you've considered, etc. This is a very broad question (which boils down to "I need to implement security, how do I do...") which is not well suited to Stack Overflow. I'll post a partial answer since I can give some guidance on your goals, and keep an eye out for a revision which makes this more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.) Authentication / Limiting visibility of data. [We wrote a guide for multitenancy here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-design-patterns-multi-tenancy-saas-applications) and [you can also use Row Level Security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/row-level-security) to enforce your needs on visibility of data within a database. You'll need to implement some way of identifying the appropriate  user context so that the database can return only the correct data. [Our security features demo utilizes RLS, which you can find on GitHub here.](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-sql-security-sample)

2.) This sounds like Role Based Access Control; Azure SQL Database offers a permissions model which can implement this on the *Database* itself, but that doesn't sound like what you need, so I'm omitting the link. However, in the context of your application, you'll need to implement permissions checks yourself for things within your application. I'm sure there are resources that can guide you through the concepts, though you may need to modify the implementation for your needs. [NIST reference page](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/SNS/rbac/) and [wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control).